# How (and when/where) init Django cache?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-1.7

I'm trying to use the Django `LocMemCache` for storing a few simple values but I'm not sure how to initialize the cache when Django starts. Django 1.7 come with [Applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/), allowing to run some code in `AppConfig.ready()`, that place would be perfect to initialize the cache, but according to Django 1.7 documentation:

> " ... Although you can access model classes as described above, avoid
>   interacting with the database in your ready() implementation."

So, let say I want to store some DB queries from my model:

```
x = MyModel.objects.count()
y = MyModel.(a really expensive query)
```

How and when should I init the cache? Is there a recommended "best practice" for doing that?
Currently, I have just added the following `cache.py` to my application, but I'm not sure if 
my code hits the database once (i.e. the first request) and then uses the cached value before (the following requests).

```
# cache.py

from django.core.cache import caches
from .models import MyModel


class Cache(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__count = MyModel.objects.count()
        self.cache = caches['cache-storage']

    @property
    def total_count(self):
        return self.cache.get('total_count', self.__count)
```

Then I use the cached values in this way:

```
# view.py

from .cache import Cache
cache = Cache()
...

   (some view)
   counter = cache.total_count
```

Answer (score 0):

That tip about using databases in ready() is generally good advice but isn't always going to work out. Some applications need to access the database based on a schedule instead of a view. The only way I've seen to implement that is from within ready().

This does create an issue because all manage.py commands will run the code in ready(). This means that the application would be accessing the database with your runtime code while running migrations or creating super users which isn't ideal.

I avoid this issue by adding a sys.argv check in ready().

```
import sys
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyApp(AppConfig):
    name = 'MyApp'

    def ready(self):
        if 'runserver' in sys.argv:
            # your code here
```